# Server Refuses SSH key

Tags: shared-hosting

I purchased shared hosting from Vexxhost.I wanted to host my Rails application with them.I was given cpanel details.I generated SSH keys using the cPanel and converted it to .ppk format.Next, i downloaded the key.But when i try SSH login using Putty, i get the message Server Refused Our Key.Then i'm prompted for the password.When i enter password, message is displayed: Shell access is not available for your account.Contact support.I did contact support, but no reply.Am I doing any mistake in the procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used cpanel to generate ssh keys, usually I do it at the ubuntu console. Is it possible that the ppk conversion has encoding issues? or it not done right?

Do you have access to a linux box? It would be simpler to test it there.

I have configured a server myself with ssh access, and if user does not have ssh access they are presented with user/pass. So it appears that your ssh credentials are denied, but your password is recognized as accurate. Authentication is happening.

About the issue of shell support. It could be that they enable shell support only if you connect with valid ssh credentials - in which case, you need to contact support.

Or, your account does not have ssh access, and you still need to contact support.

hope it helps

Comment: Could the op mention which part of this answer solved the problem? That would be great.